# variable is not getting increases?

Tags: jquery

I am loading html pages on click of next button one by one in my Div tag as shown in below code.But as requirement I want to stop/break my loop after each page is load.but when I click again on next button my variable is not getting increase its value.

```
 function loadFiles() {

      var files = ['index2.html', 'index.html','index3.html','index4.html'];
      var i=1;
      while(i<=5)
      {
           alert(i+'')
           var file = files[i];

           $('#tabpage_1').load(file + '');

           document.getElementById('txtPageNo').value = i; 
           i++;
           break;

      }
 }
```

so I want to increase my variable after loop breaks.

Comment: Did you try parsing it to Int. parseInt(i)

Comment: yes i am breaking the loop.the reason is when page get loaded I am showing page no also ..like when page1 display it will show page no 1  .document.getElementById('txtPageNo').value = i; using this line.but when second time i am cliking on my next button i want the value of i==2 then it will display me the page2 with page number 2

Comment: Please check this fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/KzWZv/

Comment: thanku sidney by define the counter outside its workng but its bad to to use counter outside the function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your variable outside your function so it doesn't initialize everytime.

```
 var i=1;
    function loadFiles() {

                var files = ['index2.html', 'index.html','index3.html','index4.html'];

                while(i<=5)
                {
                alert(i+'')
                var file = files[i];

                $('#tabpage_1').load(file + '');

                document.getElementById('txtPageNo').value = i; 
                i++;
                break;

                }
```

Comment: This is no good! Defining a counter outside of your function is bad practice. The fact that things work do not mean they are right! Please don't do this? For your own sake, this will give you bugs in larger projects, keep your scope clean!

Answer (score 0):

Because of `break` it is not updating.

Once the

```
document.getElementById('txtPageNo').value = i; 
           i++;
```

statements are get executed the loop is terminating because ofbreak.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the break statement! The position of your i variable is where it should be. Moving it outside your function would set it for all functions in that scope, not very usefull! The break simply does what it's supposed to do which is breaking the loop! If you want to break the loop you must do this for a specific condition.